# Not so much in my response

Tags: word-choice

Can I use "not so much" in my answer or is it considered informal/rude?

"Are people in your country happy?"

"Not, so much."

Comment: _Not very_ or _not always_ would be more idiomatic.

Comment: Not very without "much"?

Comment: _Not very_ implies _not very happy_ (no need to repeat the adjective). We wouldn't say _not very much happy_ - but see Stangdon's answer with regard to American usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In US English, **not so much** is informal but completely understandable.   For example, here's a book titled [*Toasters Are Easy, School Not So Much*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Toasters_Are_Easy_School_Not_So_Much/dElNLwEACAAJ?hl=en); which would be interpreted as "toasters are easy, but school is not very easy."

There should not be a comma in *not so much*, though - there is simply no purpose for it.